# If an operator is overloaded for a C++ class how could I use a default operator instead?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

[_com_ptr_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b(VS.80).aspx) has an overloaded operator&() with a side effect. If I have a variable:

```
_com_ptr_t<Interface> variable;
```

How could I retrieve its address (_com_ptr_t<Interface>* pointer) without calling the overloaded operator and triggering the side effect?

Comment: Do you want an `_com_ptr_t<Interface>*` or an `Interface*` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen this case pop up in an ISO meeting as it broke some offsetof() macro implementations (LWG 273). The solution: `&reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(variable)`

Comment: Could this ever bite me in some surprising case?

Comment: use boost::address_of. It is based on implementation provided in this post. I think it will a part of the upcoming standard.

Comment: @sharptooth: Probably not. This solution has quite reasonable behavior. Taking the address of an unsigned char lvalue is perfectly well defined, and reinterpret_cast to unsigned char& should work even if the casted object defines `operator unsigned char` itself.

Answer (score 3):

I define this utility function:

```
template<typename T>
T *GetRealAddr(T &t)
    { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&reinterpret_cast<unsigned char &>(t)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

&variable.GetInterfacePtr();

Comment: This retrieves the address of the pointer stored in the smart pointer. However, I think question is about how to get the address of the smart pointer.