# Most portable and reliable way to get the address of variable in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting

Using `&` to get an address of a variable can be problematic if the variable type has overloaded `operator&()`. For example, [_com_ptr_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28VS.80%29.aspx) has `operator&()` overloaded with a side effect of modifying the object.

Now I have a complicated set of templates with functions like this:

```
template<class T>
void process( const T* object )
{
    //whatever
}    

template<class T>
void tryProcess( T& object )
{
    process( &object )
}
```

In `tryProcess()` I need to get a `T*` pointer holding the address of the actual object of type `T`.

The above implementation of `tryProcess()` will only work allright if `class T` doesn't have `operator&()` overloaded. So if I call `tryProcess<_com_ptr_<Interface>>()` I can get unexpected results - the overloaded `operator&()` is triggered.

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142607/if-an-operator-is-overloaded-for-a-c-class-how-could-i-use-a-default-operator-i) the following workaround is [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142607/if-an-operator-is-overloaded-for-a-c-class-how-could-i-use-a-default-operator-i/1142653#1142653):

```
template<class T>
T* getAddress( T& object )
{
   return reinterpret_cast<T*>( &reinterpret_cast<char&>( object ) );
}
```

With such a function I can implement `tryProcess()` as follows:

```
template<class T>
void tryProcess( T& object )
{
    process( getAddress( object ) )
}
```

and will always get the same behavior independent of whether `class T` has `operator&()` overloaded. This introduces zero overhead with optimizations on on Visual C++ 7 - the compiler gets what to do and just gets the object address.

How portable and standard-compilant is this solution to the problem? How could it be improved?

Comment: For reference of later readers: C++11 standardised a neatly wrapped (previously `boost`) version of this idiom, as `std::addressof`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is standard-complaint. The issue was brought to the attention of the ISO C++ committee in relation to problems with `offsetof` implementations that broke on this. Amongst the solutions considered were tightening the POD definition, or adding an extra restriction on types to be used with `offsetof`. Those solutions were rejected when the `reinterpret_cast` solution was brought up. Since this offered a standard-compliant way around the problem, the committee did not see a need to add extra requirements to the `offsetof`, and left fixes to the implementations.

Answer (score 4):

[Boost `addressof`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof) is implemented with that `reinterpret_cast` trick so I'd say it's probably portable and standard-conforming.

[Here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/boost/utility/addressof.hpp#L35) you can see the code in question.

Comment: and thankfully, one no longer needs `boost`, as this is now `std::addressof`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof