# C++: getting the address of the start of an std::vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Sometimes it is useful to use the starting address of an `std::vector` and temporarily treat that address as the address of a regularly allocated buffer.
For instance replace this:

```
 char* buf = new char[size];
 fillTheBuffer(buf, size);
 useTheBuffer(buf, size);
 delete[] buf;
```

With This:

```
 vector<char> buf(size);
 fillTheBuffer(&buf[0], size);
 useTheBuffer(&buf[0], size);
```

The advantage of this is of course that the buffer is deallocated automatically and I don't have to worry about the `delete[]`.

The problem I'm having with this is when size == 0. In that case the first version works ok. An empty buffer is "allocated" and the subsequent functions do nothing size they get size == 0.
The second version however fails if size == 0 since calling `buf[0]` may rightly contain an assertion that `0 < size`.

So is there an alternative to the idiom `&buf[0]` that returns the address of the start of the vector even if the vector is empty?

I've also considered using `buf.begin()` but according to the standard it isn't even guaranteed to return a pointer.

Comment: This looks like an oversight in the STL library.  C++ allows you to allocate `new T[0]` and return a valid pointer for situations like this, but most implementations of the STL assert just in case you're assigning to that element or something.

Comment: How would it know the difference between `&buf[0]` and `buf[0] = 1` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you'd just have to check.

Perhaps a utility function:

```
template <class T, class Alloc>
T* data(std::vector<T, Alloc>& vec)
{
    return vec.empty() ? 0 : &vec[0];
}

template <class T, class Alloc>
const T* data(const std::vector<T, Alloc>& vec)
{
    return vec.empty() ? 0 : &vec[0];
}
```

Comment: 1st remark: is it worth investing on `boost::addressof` in case `T` has an overloaded `&` operator ?

2nd remark: a second template parameter `Alloc` would make the function a bit more universal.

Comment: @Matthieu: Regarding the first remark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719832/why-is-overloading-operator-prohibited-for-classes-stored-in-stl-containers. You can't store a type for which `&t` doesn't return its address. - Second remark added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no function for that, even though `std::basic_string` has `data()` which does exactly what you need.

You'll have to use something like `buf.size()?&buf[0]:0;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be safe in either case. I believe that the differences between vector::operator[int] and vector::at(int) is that the [] operator overload specifically does *not* perform bounds checking. Using buf[0] should be free of assertions!

Comment: Sadly you are mistaken. MSVC2008's vector has assertions on `operator[]`.

Comment: As a follow up, I've learned that the following `#define _SECURE_SCL 0` will disable this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change fillTheBuffer and useTheBuffer to take a pair of iterators, then you'll be solving the problem the same way the standard library solved it.