# Overloading unary operator &

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Let's consider a class with overloaded unary operator & (Address-of). Let it be `class A`

```
template <class C>
class A
{
public:
    C * operator &()
    {
        return &data;
    }
    //...
private:
    C data;
}
```

Now I want to pass to some function a pointer of type `A` to fill its `data`. Let us call it `f`

```
void f(A * auto_containter)
{
    //...
}
```

But it is clear why the code bellow wouldn't work (even wouldn't compile). It is because the overloaded operator is called.

```
A a;
f(&a);
```

The question is following:

Is there any syntax to pass address of `a` to `f`? If no, then for me it is very strange why it is allowed to overload unary `operator &`, because it makes code more buggy and difficult to understand. Or there are some other reasons?

Comment: Related: [Why is overloading operator&() prohibited for classes stored in STL containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719832/why-is-overloading-operator-prohibited-for-classes-stored-in-stl-containers)

Comment: Abusing operator overloading does make the code harder to decode (and thus understand). Like all tools that are provided don't abuse them.

Comment: You asked for *syntax* so this isn't an answer, but you could write `A * A::addressof() { return this; }`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `std::addressof` function(or `boost::addressof` pre C++11). In any case, overloading unary & is highly dubious. Why do it instead of having a named function that returns the address of your data?

Comment: I agree that it's dubious, possibly even a mistake in the standard to permit it since the address of an object is a more fundamental concept than the operator used to obtain it, which is why every type works with `operator&` by default, unlike say `operator+`. But the classic answer to the "why do it" is to say, "I don't want to use a named function because I want to write generic code that takes addresses, and works with `int`, but when this class is used in that generic code I want it to use this other address". So explain why that's a mistake and we're done ;-)

Comment: For instance, you could change the generic code to use a type traits template to get the address, rather than unary &.

Comment: This functionality was included in C++11 as `std::addressof()`.

Answer (score 18):

> Is there any syntax to pass address of `a` to `f`?

Yes, there's ugly syntax:

```
f( reinterpret_cast<A*>( &reinterpret_cast<char&>(a) ) );
```

[`boost::addressof`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof) is a nice and generic wrapper around it.

Comment: Can anyone explain this code? Especially the reinterpret_cast<char&>(a). What exactly is happening there under the hood?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any syntax to pass address of a to f?

Others have already pointed out `boost::addressof`. The mechanism it relies on is a standard-guaranteed use of the *built-in* address operator for a `reinterpret_cast` to reference type. The Boost function just wraps the rather verbose and awkward combination of casts.

> If no, then for me it is very strange why it is allowed to overload unary operator &,
>   because if will make code more buggy and difficult to understand. Or there are some other
>   reasons?

In some cases it can be more convenient. For example, a smart pointer class might offer [a custom address operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31k6d0k7%28VS.80%29.aspx) in order to support writing `&p` as actual argument to a `T**` formal argument. However, I think nowadays it’s generally recognized that it isn’t all that good an idea.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

Why would you ever want to overload the unary `operator&`?

Aside from that, there is `boost::addressof`.

Comment: I my opinion: It would have been very useful to have `std::reference_wrapper` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper to overload `operator&` to `return _ptr;`. Unfortunately it was not implemented and the resulting user code is less generic that what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

This is why [`boost::addressof`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof) was invented.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario never really comes up, because anyone who is writing that function will take a reference, not a pointer. Plus, you forgot to instantiate A with an example type for C.