# overloaded address-of operator. How do I know object's adress

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, address-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overloading unary operator &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410333/overloading-unary-operator)

```
class A
{
public:
    A* operator&()
    {
        return NULL;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A obj;
    A* ptr=&obj;//ptr=NULL
    //determining obj's address here
}
```

It is possible to determine address of object of such class?

Comment: [Overloading unary operator &](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410333/overloading-unary-operator)