# Casting base class pointer to pointer of class member

Tags: c++

**Question:**

We do have a template based class, that provides some functionality around a primitive type (e.g. serializing, deserializing, ...)

```
template <typename PRIM_TYPE> class WrappedPrimitive
{
public:
    PRIM_TYPE v;

    //lots of other methods, including serialization and deserialization

    PRIM_TYPE & operator= (const PRIM_TYPE & value) { v = value; return v; }
    operator PRIM_TYPE() const          { return v; }
};
typedef WrappedPrimitive<float>        WrappedPrimitiveFloat;
```

Let's say I have a function

```
void maninpulateFloat(float *f) {*f = 5.0f;}
```

Is there any way to add some class function, such that it returns the address of the `v`member when casting from `*WrappedPrimitiveFloat` to `*float`. (Or in general from `*WrappedPrimitive<PRIM_TYPE>` to `*PRIM_TYPE`?

```
WrappedPrimitiveFloat myfloat;
manipulateFloat(&myfloat.v) // This works
manipulateFloat(&myfloat)   // Is there any way to make this work?
```

**Background:**

I know it is maybe not a good idea, but the reason I'd like it is because we ported the code to Linux, where myfloat will actually be a float and not some wrapped value. Right now, we need to distinguish these places with

```
#ifdef _WIN32
manipulateFloat(&myfloat.v)
#else
manipulateFloat(&myfloat)
#endif
```

which is also really ugly. Alternatively, I'd be happy with a line of code that works on both Windows/Linux.

**What I have tried**

It is possible to overload the operator& function,

```
PRIM_TYPE * operator& () {return &v;}
```

but according to this post [Overloading unary operator &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410333/overloading-unary-operator) it is not the best idea, as using & will always return a `PRIM_TYPE*`.

Comment: What's the problem with overloading `operator&`?

Comment: If your function took the float by reference, you could add `operator TYPE&()` If not you will have to store a float (value or reference) in a local variable first.

Comment: @KerrekSB Do you recommend overloading `operator&` for every class that has a conversion operator?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the function to take a reference instead of a pointer. In case of a local variable, I will of course have to write it back to the original afterwards, as it will get manipulated.

Comment: @NeilKirk: No, I recommend shooting on sight everyone who overloads `operator&`. But that wasn't the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a template `get_address()` function and use it everywhere you need instead of unary `&`:

```
template <typename PRIM_TYPE> class WrappedPrimitive
{
public:
    operator PRIM_TYPE() const { return v; }

    // these conversions are necessary to implement
    operator PRIM_TYPE&() { return v; }
    operator const PRIM_TYPE&() const { return v; } 
};


template <typename PRIM_TYPE>
PRIM_TYPE* get_address(PRIM_TYPE& v) {
    return &v;
}

template <typename PRIM_TYPE>
PRIM_TYPE* get_address(WrappedPrimitive<PRIM_TYPE>& wp) {
    return &static_cast<PRIM_TYPE&>(wp);
}

template <typename PRIM_TYPE>
const PRIM_TYPE* get_address(const WrappedPrimitive<PRIM_TYPE>& wp) {
    return &static_cast<const PRIM_TYPE&>(wp);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de2d54c597322d70)