# can vector contain a smart pointer which overload operator &?

Tags: c++

For example, I have such a smart pointer:

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPointer
{
public:
    ....
    T* operator & () { return m_p; } 
private:
    T* m_p;  
}

void foo()
{
    std::vector<SmartPointer<int> >vec;
    vec.push_back(....);
    vec.resize(.....);
    ......
}
```

Is this usage safe? I try it in MINGW4.4, It work ok....

In fact, those code is use work for COM, when I wanted to get a object, I need to do these

```
SmpartPointer<COMObj> spObj;
HRESULT hr = xxxxx->QueryInterface(&spObj);
```

then i wanted to store the pointer in a vector, so

```
std::vector<SmpartPointer<COMObj> >vec;
.....
```

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be safe? `vector` are templated, so anything you do will be based on a template should be as safe as anything else.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? If `p` were a normal pointer, you wouldn't expect `&p` to return the pointer. Giving overloaded operators different semantics is a good way to cause bugs later.

Comment: If the implementation of `std::vector` requires a raw pointer to its data internally, I'd expect it to use `std::addressof` or `allocator::address` to obtain it.

Comment: Overloading operator& is questionable in most, if not all cases. It's counterintuitive and does not make sense for smartpointers.

Comment: I don't remember any requirements that client classes of `std::vector` *not* overload the operator, so I assume it's fine. Your use of operator overloading is the archetype of a Bad Idea, though.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719832/why-is-overloading-operator-prohibited-for-classes-stored-in-stl-containers

Comment: you may want to use 'operator T*()'

Answer (score 3):

In C++03, there is no *explicit* requirement that value types in containers do not overload unary `operator&`; however per 23.1p3 the objects stored are required to model `CopyConstructible` (20.1.3p1, Table 30).  This in turn requires that the expression `&t` should yield a value of type `T *` that denotes the address of `t`.  So overloaded unary `operator&` is permissible, but only if it has the "correct" return type and returns the correct value.

Your `operator&` is invalid; it should return `SmartPointer<T> *`.

In C++11 this was relaxed (through the use of `std::addressof`) so unary `operator&` can have any type and return any value.

In all versions of the standard, the type parameter of `complex` and `valarray` must not overload unary `operator&`; this is to allow them to be treated as contiguous storage.