# How can I reliably get an object's address when operator& is overloaded?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, memory-address

Consider the following program:

```
struct ghost
{
    // ghosts like to pretend that they don't exist
    ghost* operator&() const volatile { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    ghost clyde;
    ghost* clydes_address = &clyde; // darn; that's not clyde's address :'( 
}
```

How do I get `clyde`'s address?

I'm looking for a solution that will work equally well for all types of objects.  A C++03 solution would be nice, but I'm interested in C++11 solutions too.  If possible, let's avoid any implementation-specific behavior.

I am aware of C++11's `std::addressof` function template, but am not interested in using it here:  I'd like to understand how a Standard Library implementor might implement this function template.

Comment: @jalf:  That strategy is acceptable, but now that I've punched said individuals in the head, how do I work around their abominable code?  :-)

Comment: @jalf Uhm, sometimes you *need* to overload this operator, and return a proxy object. Though I can’t think of an example just now.

Comment: @Konrad: me either. If you need that, I'd suggest that a better option might be to rethink your design, because overloading that operator just causes too many problems. :)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719832/why-is-overloading-operator-prohibited-for-classes-stored-in-stl-containers/2719880#2719880).

Comment: @Konrad: In roughly 20 years of C++ programming I have _once_ attempted to overload that operator. That was at the very beginning of those twenty years. Oh, and I failed to make that usable. Consequently, the [operator overloading FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) says "The unary address-of operator should never be overloaded." You'll get a free beer the next time we meet if you can come up with a convincing example for overloading this operator. (I know you're leaving Berlin, so I can safely offer this `:)`)

Comment: `CComPtr<>` and `CComQIPtr<>` have an overloaded `operator&`

Comment: @Simon: but the important question is **should** they have an overloaded `operator&`?

Comment: Well, it allows pointers to them to be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the contained type... But indeed, I'd return a proxy object that is convertible to `T **` and `CComPtr<T> *`.

Comment: Don't do it like this. It will trigger an `operator char&()`.

Comment: @Simon Richter: I till remember spending  a day or so debugging and fixing a problem triggered by this. GAAAH! --- the `operator &` should use an `interface ** OutPtr()` / `interface ** InOutPtr()` instead, that would make it explicit in the call (with acceptable overhead)

Comment: Here're two very similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/1142607/57428 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2333321/57428

Comment: @curiousguy:  Many interesting questions in life tend to be about unpractical things.  That said, this question is certainly a practical one for anyone writing a C++ Standard Library implementation.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis "_That said, this question is certainly a practical one for anyone writing a C++ Standard Library implementation_" for what?

Comment: @curiousguy:  `std::addressof` must be able to obtain the address of an object, even if the object is of a type that overloads arbitrary operators, including conversion operators and the unary `&`.  Further, the Standard Library containers must be instantiable and usable with those perverse types as well (this requirement is new in C++11; it was not present in C++98/03).

Comment: OTOH: "Numeric type requirements" [numeric.requirements] "it does not overload unary operator&."

Comment: @SimonRichter how is CCom*** to be considered something that doesn't need its design rethought???

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Update:** in C++11, one may use `std::addressof` instead of `boost::addressof`.

---

Let us first copy the code from Boost, minus the compiler work around bits:

```
template<class T>
struct addr_impl_ref
{
  T & v_;

  inline addr_impl_ref( T & v ): v_( v ) {}
  inline operator T& () const { return v_; }

private:
  addr_impl_ref & operator=(const addr_impl_ref &);
};

template<class T>
struct addressof_impl
{
  static inline T * f( T & v, long ) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
        &const_cast<char&>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(v)));
  }

  static inline T * f( T * v, int ) { return v; }
};

template<class T>
T * addressof( T & v ) {
  return addressof_impl<T>::f( addr_impl_ref<T>( v ), 0 );
}
```

> What happens if we pass a **reference to function** ?

*Note: `addressof` cannot be used with a pointer to function*

In C++ if `void func();` is declared, then `func` is a reference to a function taking no argument and returning no result. This reference to a function can be trivially converted into a pointer to function -- from `@Konstantin`: According to 13.3.3.2 both `T &` and `T *` are indistinguishable for functions. The 1st one is an Identity conversion and the 2nd one is Function-to-Pointer conversion both having "Exact Match" rank (13.3.3.1.1 table 9).

The *reference to function* pass through `addr_impl_ref`, there is an ambiguity in the overload resolution for the choice of `f`, which is solved thanks to the dummy argument `0`, which is an `int` first and could be promoted to a `long` (Integral Conversion).

Thus we simply returns the pointer.

> What happens if we pass a type with a conversion operator ?

If the conversion operator yields a `T*` then we have an ambiguity: for `f(T&,long)` an Integral Promotion is required for the second argument while for `f(T*,int)` the conversion operator is called on the first *(thanks to @litb)*

That's when `addr_impl_ref` kicks in. The C++ Standard mandates that a conversion sequence may contain at most one user-defined conversion. By wrapping the type in `addr_impl_ref` and forcing the use of a conversion sequence already, we "disable" any conversion operator that the type comes with.

Thus the `f(T&,long)` overload is selected (and the Integral Promotion performed).

> What happens for any other type ?

Thus the `f(T&,long)` overload is selected, because there the type does not match the `T*` parameter.

*Note: from the remarks in the file regarding Borland compatibility, arrays do not decay to pointers, but are passed by reference.*

> What happens in this overload ?

We want to avoid applying `operator&` to the type, as it may have been overloaded.

The Standard guarantees that `reinterpret_cast` may be used for this work (see @Matteo Italia's answer: 5.2.10/10).

Boost adds some niceties with `const` and `volatile` qualifiers to avoid compiler warnings (and properly use a `const_cast` to remove them).

- Cast `T&` to `char const volatile&`
- Strip the `const` and `volatile`
- Apply the `&` operator to take the address
- Cast back to a `T*`

The `const`/`volatile` juggling is a bit of black magic, but it does simplify the work (rather than providing 4 overloads). Note that since `T` is unqualified, if we pass a `ghost const&`, then `T*` is `ghost const*`, thus the qualifiers have not really been lost.

**EDIT:** the pointer overload is used for pointer to functions, I amended the above explanation somewhat. I still do not understand why it is *necessary* though.

The following [ideone output](http://ideone.com/338NX) sums this up, somewhat.

Comment: "What happens if we pass a pointer ?" part is incorrect. If we pass a pointer to some type U the addressof function the type 'T' is inferred to be 'U*' and addr_impl_ref will have two overloads: 'f(U*&, long)' and 'f(U**,int)', obviously the first one will be selected.

Comment: @Konstantin: right, I had thought that the two `f` overloads where function templates, whereas they are regular member functions of a template class, thanks for pointing it out. (Now I just need to figure out what is the use of the overload, any tip ?)

Comment: This is a great, well-explained answer.  I kind of figured there was a bit more to this than just "cast through `char*`."  Thank you, Matthieu.

Comment: @James: I have had much help from @Konstantin who would strike my head with a stick any time I made a mistake :D

Comment: @Matthieu: Did I? :D Probably we are just interested in similar questions here, nothing personal. :)

Comment: Why would it need to work around types that have a conversion function? Would it not prefer the exact match over invoking any conversion function to `T*`? EDIT: Now I see. It would, but with the `0` argument it would end up in a *criss-cross*, so would be ambiguous.

Comment: @James: :D  @litb: there are two conversions we wish to avoid. The conversion to `T*` leads to an ambiguity and the conversion to `T&` may point to another object. The latter would really bite us, unnoticed (at compile-time).

Comment: @Matthieu, no the conversion to `T&` can never happen because the argument is a `T` already. This is only to avoid the *criss-cross*.

Comment: @James http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519282/why-is-this-ambiguity-here/3525172#3525172

Comment: "_then func is a reference to a function_" Hug? There is no reference here!

Comment: In C++11 we can now just use std::addressof

Comment: @paulm: Right! Edited as the first line.

Comment: it can switch int and long ?  

static inline T * f( T & v, int) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
        &const_cast<char&>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(v)));
  }

  static inline T * f( T * v, long) { return v; }

Comment: @zpeng: I am not quite sure, to be honest, since a pointer to reference is invalid and a reference to pointer is valid it seems to me it makes sense to privilege the `T*` function and thus force a conversion before access to the `T&`... but maybe I am just paranoid because I cannot think of a counter-example right now.

Answer (score 106):

Use [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof).

You can think of it as doing the following behind the scenes:

1. Reinterpret the object as a reference-to-char
2. Take the address of that (won’t call the overload)
3. Cast the pointer back to a pointer of your type.

Existing implementations (including Boost.Addressof) do exactly that, just taking additional care of `const` and `volatile` qualification.

Comment: I like this explanation better than the selected on as it can be readily understood.

Answer (score 49):

The trick behind [`boost::addressof`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/utility/addressof.hpp) and the implementation provided by @Luc Danton relies on the magic of the `reinterpret_cast`; the standard explicitly states at §5.2.10 ¶10 that

> An lvalue expression of type `T1` can be cast to the type “reference to `T2`” if an expression of type “pointer to `T1`” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to `T2`” using a `reinterpret_cast`. That is, a reference cast `reinterpret_cast<T&>(x)` has the same effect as the conversion `*reinterpret_cast<T*>(&x)` with the built-in `&` and `*` operators. The result is an lvalue that refers to the same object as the source lvalue, but with a different type.

Now, this allows us to convert an arbitrary object reference to a `char &` (with a cv qualification if the reference is cv-qualified), because any pointer can be converted to a (possibly cv-qualified) `char *`. Now that we have a `char &`, the operator overloading on the object is no longer relevant, and we can obtain the address with the builtin `&` operator.

The boost implementation adds a few steps to work with cv-qualified objects: the first `reinterpret_cast` is done to `const volatile char &`, otherwise a plain `char &` cast wouldn't work for `const` and/or `volatile` references (`reinterpret_cast` cannot remove `const`). Then the `const` and `volatile` is removed with `const_cast`, the address is taken with `&`, and a final `reinterpet_cast` to the "correct" type is done.

The `const_cast` is needed to remove the `const`/`volatile` that could have been added to non-const/volatile references, but it does not "harm" what was a `const`/`volatile` reference in first place, because the final `reinterpret_cast` will re-add the cv-qualification if it was there in first place (`reinterpret_cast` cannot remove the `const` but can add it).

<s>As for the rest of the code in `addressof.hpp`, it seems that most of it is for workarounds. The `static inline T * f( T * v, int )` seems to be needed only for the Borland compiler, but its presence introduces the need for `addr_impl_ref`, otherwise pointer types would be caught by this second overload.</s>

<s>***Edit***: the various overloads have a different function, see [@Matthieu M. excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494591/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-address-of-an-object/6495205#6495205).</s>

Well, I'm no longer sure of this either; I should further investigate that code, but now I'm cooking dinner :) , I'll have a look at it later.

Comment: Matthieu M. explanation regarding passing pointer to addressof is incorrect. Don't spoil your great answer with such edits :)

Comment: "good appetit", further investigation shows that the overload is called for reference to functions `void func();` `boost::addressof(func);`. However removing the overload does not prevent gcc 4.3.4 from compiling the code and producing the same output, so I still don't understand why it is *necessary* to have this overload.

Comment: @Matthieu: It looks to be a bug in gcc. According to 13.3.3.2 both T & and T * are indistinguishable for functions. The 1st one is an Identity conversion and the 2nd one is Function-to-Pointer conversion both having "Exact Match" rank (13.3.3.1.1 table 9). So it's necessary to have additional argument.

Comment: @Matthieu: Just tried it with gcc 4.3.4 (http://ideone.com/2f34P) and got ambiguity as expected. Did you tried overloaded member functions like in addressof implementation or free function templates? The latter one (like http://ideone.com/vjCRs) will result in 'T *' overload to be chosen due to temlate argument deduction rules (14.8.2.1/2).

Comment: @Konstantin: I add not thought of using template functions, I did thought that both function pointer and function reference were indistinguishable but did not dig up the Standard, thanks for the reference.

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin "_The 1st one is an Identity conversion and the 2nd one is Function-to-Pointer conversion_" so the compiler should prefer the first one.

Comment: @curiousguy: Why do you think it should? I've referenced specific C++ standard parts prescribing what should compiler do and all compilers I have access to (including but not limited to gcc 4.3.4, comeau-online, VC6.0-VC2010) report ambiguity just as I've described. Could you please elaborate your reasoning regarding this case?

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin "_Why do you think it should?_" Because I did not checked the issue completely. My bad. "_I've referenced specific C++ standard parts prescribing what should compiler_" Actually, you only mentioned part of the story. There is more than the "rank", and the table 9 you mentioned has more than one column.

Comment: @curiousguy: Well, I think, comments are just not suitable enough for fully elaborated discussion of such stuff. If you like you could ask corresponding question here and I'm sure you'll get elaborated and detailed answers. Still, the most relevant part of standard is 13.3.3.2 describing ordering relation for standard conversion sequences. Everything else should be easily found using references provided in this part.

Answer (score 12):

I've seen an implementation of `addressof` do this:

```
char* start = &reinterpret_cast<char&>(clyde);
ghost* pointer_to_clyde = reinterpret_cast<ghost*>(start);
```

Don't ask me how conforming this is!

Comment: Legal. `char*` is the listed exception to type aliasing rules.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm not saying this is not conforming. I'm saying that you should not ask me :)

Comment: @DeadMG There is no aliasing problem here. The question is: is `reinterpret_cast<char*>` well defined.

Comment: @curiousguy and the answer is yes, it's always allowed to cast any pointer type to `[unsigned] char *` and thereby read the object representation of the pointed-at object. This is another area where `char` has special privileges.

Comment: @underscore_d Just because a cast is "always allowed" doesn't mean you can do anything with the result of the cast.

Comment: @curiousguy I should've been more clear about things that are implicit in my comment, in order to avoid ambiguity or pedantry: What is specifically allowed is to _dereference the resulting pointer_, which is of course a prerequisite to read the object representation. In most other cases, dereferencing a `reinterpret_cast`ed pointer (unless it's since been cast _back_) is implementation-defined behaviour _if we're lucky_... or worse.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [boost::addressof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof) and its implementation.

Comment: The Boost code, while interesting, does not explain how its technique works (nor does it explain why two overloads are needed).

Comment: do you mean 'static inline T * f( T * v, int )' overload? Looks like it needed for Borland C workaround only. Approach used there is pretty straightforward. The only subtle (nonstandard) thing there is conversion of 'T&' to 'char&'. Although standard, allows cast from 'T*' to 'char*' there seems to be no such requirements for reference casting. Nevertheless, one might expect it to work exactly the same on most compilers.

Comment: @Konstantin: the overload is used because for a pointer, `addressof` returns the pointer itself. It's arguable whether it's what the user wanted or not, but it's how it specified.

Comment: @Matthieu: are you sure? As far as I can tell, any type (including pointer types) is wrapped inside an `addr_impl_ref`, so the pointer overload should never be called...

Comment: @Matthieu: ok, now that you explained it in your answer it makes sense.

Comment: @Matteo, @Konstantin: I got it wrong (I thought, don't know why, that the two overloads within `addressof_impl` had different template parameters (auto detected)... Looking further...

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin this doesn't really answer the question, as all you say is to *where to* look for the answer, not *what is the answer*.