# Why would anyone want to overload the & (address-of) operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, address-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What legitimate reasons exist to overload the unary operator& ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495977/what-legitimate-reasons-exist-to-overload-the-unary-operator)

I just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494591/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-address-of-an-object), and I can't help but wonder:

Why would anyone possibly want to overload the `&` ("address-of") operator?

```
SomeClass* operator&() const {
    return address_of_object;
}
```

Is there any legitimate use case?

Comment: @Matti: We can flag for merge. That's better than duplicating the answers as well as the question.

Comment: @Tomalak: Whoa. I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @Matti: I'm not 100% convinced that it is, but I've heard rumours... :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're dealing with any sort of wrapper objects, you might want or need to transparently forward the access to the wrapper to the contained object. In that case, you can't return a pointer to the wrapper, but need to overload the address-of operator to return a pointer to the contained object.

Comment: Heh, I searched for "c++ overload address of" exactly to find out whether I can do this. Thanks for the extremely quick reassurance :-)

Answer (score 8):

Because they're evil and want you to suffer.

Or I guess if you are using proxy objects?  I *suppose* you might want to return a pointer to the managed object instead of the container - although i'd rather do that with a getter function.  Otherwise you'd have to remember to use things like [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof).

Comment: I guess the point of a proxy object is that you don't know it's there. (Or you act as if you didn't knew.) In particular, you don't know about it's address. It's usually a temporary anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, for debugging (if you want to trace any access or reference, you might want to put a log line on any call to `&`, `*` or `->`).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in productive code already.

But there, a binary representation of the content of a `struct` was returned, not just `0`.

And the usecase was simple: Binary operations.

Comment: Binary operations with unary `&`?

Comment: I will look if i find the code again, then i'll post an example. Sounds strange, looks funny ( i think ugly) but maybe the author thought its nicer to use the `&` twice ;)

Comment: because why have it do something that makes sense, when you can instead do... _that_. :/