# Will "*&var" return the value stored in "var"?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dereference

If:

```
int var = 0;
&var;   //--> returns the address of "var"
```

and:

```
int *p = &var;
*p;   //--> returns the value pointed to by "p", the value stored in "var"
```

then shouldn't (however redundant):

```
*&var;  //--> returns the value stored in "var"
*var;   //--> throw an error (or return the value stored in "var")?
```

I have no way to compile C++ code just now, but I'd like to figure out these operators.

Comment: There are free online compilers, e.g. ideone or Coliru

Comment: Just for reference, you can use an online compiler like [this one](http://ideone.com/), for example.

Comment: Probably a little bit too sophisticated for now, but you can come back to this one later. You can *overload* the address-of operator `&`. If this is the case, `*&var` may be different from `var`. I hope that you never face code where this is the case though. Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495977/what-legitimate-reasons-exist-to-overload-the-unary-operator

Answer (score 4):

```
*&var;  //--> returns the value stored in "var"
```

Yes, `&var` is a pointer that points to `var`, then `*&var` is the same as `var`.

```
*var;   //--> throw an error (or return the value stored in "var")?
```

This doesn't compile because you can't deference an `int`.

Comment: Can you only dereference address-values -- is there such a thing?
If there is, how does the C++ interpreter 'know' a value is of type 'address'?
If there isn't, how would the C++ interpreter not confuse a pointer with some other binary signal?  Possibly one that I write?

Comment: The compiler "knows" because you declare variables to be a pointer type, or not. When you declared `int* p` you are saying to the compliler that `p` is of the type "pointer to an int". And the compiler will only allow pointer types to be de-referenced.

Comment: Since this is C++, you should definitely write about references here. `*&var` yields a _reference_ to var, not its value, i.e `*&var = 17` will modify var.

Comment: @Quentin `*&var` is an lvalue. But I'm not sure about the word *reference* here, I mean, there's no references in C, but `*&var = 17;` will modify `var` as well.

Comment: They were not called "references" in C yet and weren't declarable/nameable indeed, but they were already there. In any case the question is tagged "C++", not "C" :)

Comment: IIRC C also named them lvalue's.

Comment: @MSalters I'm no language-lawyer so I may be mistaken on C terminology here. But I'm quite sure that in C++ "lvalue" refers to `var` itself, and something like `*&var` returns a lvalue reference (which is thus not an lvalue itself).

Comment: @Quentin: It's not a function call, so it doesn't return anything. It's an "lvalue expression". As is `var` by itself.