# What does operator.*() do?

Tags: c++, operators

What does `operator.*()` do? What is it's purpose?

It is documented as [Pointer-to-member](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) and exactly the same as `->*`. Are those two identical?

Scott Meyers in More effective C++, Item 7 explains that `.*` is NOT overloadable, while `->*` IS. Why is that?

Comment: `.*` is to `->*` what `.` is to `->`.

Comment: That page just says it has the same precedence as `->*`, not that it's "exactly the same". It's similar, but applied to objects/references like `.`, rather than pointers like `->`.

Comment: @hvd No, the OP is right. These operators do exist. [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx) describes how they are used and how they differ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That seems like a non sequitur. I never claimed the operators don't exist.

Comment: @5gon12eder C++ really does have `.*` and `->*` operators, where `*` is part of the operator syntax.

Comment: @5gon12eder No, no. It’s not a placeholder at all, and `.*` and `->*` *are* real operators.

Comment: @hvd Oops, I got to do some reading.  Thanks.  I have always parsed these constructs as `.(*x)` pr `->(*x)` but it seems that this was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As answered already, no, `.*` and `->*` don't mean the same thing. Assuming no overloaded operators are used, `a->*b` means `(*a).*b`, i.e. `.*` is used with class types, and `->*` is used with pointers to class types. It's just like how `a->b` means `(*a).b` if the built-in operators are used.

Neither `.` nor `.*` is overloadable because it was not clear when the standard was written whether that would have negative consequences. `.` is the more useful of these, and [is still being considered for a future version of C++](http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#151), but the first proposal of making that overloadable [dates back to 1990](http://groups.google.com/groups?selm=1992Jul14.190540.2425%40microsoft.com&oe=UTF-8&output=gplain) (well before the first C++ standard was published). Some of the issues that need to be resolved involve choosing what to do when `a.b` is valid with the built-in operator, but *not* valid as (pseudo-code) `(a.operator.()).b`. Does the built-in operator then get used in its place, or should this be an error? Neither seems particularly desirable.

Some of the proposals for overloading the `.` operator also include overloading the `.*` operator, others don't. There isn't all that much demand for making `.*` overloadable by itself, so if it does get accepted at some point, it'll probably happen along with `.`, and that's been taking a very long time.

Comment: Were it possible, I'd expect it to be much like overloading `&` : one-way ticket to getting fired :p

Comment: @Quentin [There are a few good uses of overloaded `operator&`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495977/what-legitimate-reasons-exist-to-overload-the-unary-operator), and when the built-in operator is needed, it's possible to get the address without relying on `&`, just like it'd be possible to call a member function directly on an object even if `operator.` is overloaded. (You'd be able to write `addressof(obj)->fun()` instead of `obj.fun()`.)

Answer (score 2):

it's designed to be used with :

left operand of class type

right operand of pointer to a "member of this class type"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Foo{
public:
  int f(string str){
    std::cout<<"Foo::f()"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int (Foo::*fptr) (string) = &Foo::f;
  Foo obj;
  (obj.*fptr)("str");//call: Foo::f() through an object
  Foo* p=&obj;
  (p->*fptr)("str");//call: Foo::f() through a pointer
}
```

note that i didn't produce this code, it comes from a tutorial which explained how it works, but not actually what's the purpose

the difference about overloadability is the same as between . and ->, so it's not particular to this case and there's been subject about this like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520035/why-cant-you-overload-the-operator-in-c)

commitee are deciding those kinds of things, not everytimes with obvious reason, but this is coherent with the fact that x-> can be seen as (*x).,
.() cannot be overload, but *() can be, so the combination of those implies that -> can be overload, because "one part of it with a different writing" can be overload

what i say last is just my mind trying to go on admiring c++ for his beauty and coherence

Answer (score 0):

Its a pointer a member. Example:

```
// This functions waits until predicate evalues false
void waitSomething(bool (one_class::*predicate)(),one_class& that)
{
    while ((that.*predicate)())
    {
        sleep(100);
    }
}
```

You can call as:

```
one_class a;
waitSomething(&a::*predicate,a); //predicate is an internal function member
```

You can use for attributes too.

->* is for pointers:

```
// This functions waits until predicate evalues false
void waitSomething(bool (one_class::*predicate)(),one_class* that)
{
    while ((that->*predicate)())
    {
        sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, OP also asks why `.*` is not overloadable.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will be particularly helpful for you but this is what I have learned thanks to your question.

A reasonable use-case for overloading operator `->*` ([which is a real thing…](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access)) alongside with operator `->` could be to provide transparent access to a managed object (thinking of `std::unique_ptr`) also for indirect member access.  Note, however, that `std::unique_ptr` overloads operator `->` but not operator `->*`.

Like we cannot overload operator `.`, we also cannot overload operator `.*` because [it was decided to be like this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#overload-dot).

So here is a somewhat silly class that wraps an object and pretends to be a pointer to it.  The example would make more sense if the managed object were held by a pointer with managed life-time but I wanted to avoid cluttering the example with resource management code that is unrelated to member access.

```
// C++14

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class PointerLike
{

private:

  T object_;

public:

  template<typename... ParamT>
  PointerLike(ParamT&&... params) : object_ {std::forward<ParamT>(params)...}
  {
  }

  // The 'const' overloads have been omitted for the sake of brevity.

  // "Dereferences" the handle and obtains a reference to the managed object.
  T&
  operator*()
  {
    return this->object_;
  }

  // Accesses a member of the managed object.
  T *
  operator->()
  {
    return &(this->object_);
  }

  // Indirectly invokes a function member of the managed object.
  template<typename RetT, typename... ArgT>
  decltype(auto)
  operator->*(RetT(T::*mfunc)(ArgT...))
  {
    return [=](ArgT... args)->RetT{
      return (object_.*mfunc)(std::forward<ArgT>(args)...);
    };
  }
};

int
main()
{
  typedef std::vector<int> ivec;
  typedef void (ivec::*append_member_type)(int&&);
  append_member_type append = &ivec::push_back;
  PointerLike<ivec> pl {1, 2, 3, 4};
  pl->push_back(5);    // pointer-like direct member access
  (pl->*append)(6);    // pointer-like indirect member access ("natural" way)
  ((*pl).*append)(7);  // pointer-like indirect member access
  for (const auto& v : *pl)
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

The program will output the integers from 1 to 7.