# Is there any advantage of using std::addressof() function template instead of using operator& in C++?

Tags: c++

If *addressof* `operator&` works well then why C++ has introduced `addressof()` function? The `&` operator is part of C++ from the beginning - why this new function is introduced then? Does it offer any advantages over C's `&` operator?

Comment: It looks very close to a duplicate to me but I don't feel strong enough to dup hammer it myself but it is relevant regardless. It would be more convincing if you explained why you felt it was different.

Comment: One would be hard-pressed to find a page discussing `std::addressof` without mentioning its ability to bypass overloaded unary `operator&`. This question shows zero research effort.

Comment: @T.C.: If this question shows 0 research effort then it would not be possible to get so much upvotes for it.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The unary `operator&` might be overloaded for class types to give you something other than the object's address, while  `std::addressof()` will always give you its actual address.
[Contrived example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3306f9e2d427012f):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A* operator &() {return nullptr;}
};

int main () {
    A a;
    std::cout << &a << '\n';              // Prints 0
    std::cout << std::addressof(a);       // Prints a's actual address
}
```

If you wonder when doing this is useful:
[What legitimate reasons exist to overload the unary operator&?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495977/what-legitimate-reasons-exist-to-overload-the-unary-operator)