# C++: Remove == or any other operator for specific types

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, operators, equals-operator

If I have a class called classA that has a typecast overload of classB and classC, how can I disable the == operator for classA being typed as classC?

```
class classA{
   operator classB();
   operator classC();

   //Remove this comparison possibility:
   operator ==(classC firstObject,classC secondObject);
}
```

Follow over from this question:

[Ambiguous overload when using many typecasts operator overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956250/ambiguous-overload-when-using-many-typecasts-operator-overloads?noredirect=1#comment63362352_37956250)

Comment: make operatorB and operatorC explicit? This is not a complete example. Can you post a minimal, complete example pls?

Comment: Your code won't work, and not just because of a missing `;`.  You've got a sort of trinary operator there.  `operator==` either needs one argument if it's a member, or 2 if it's a nonmember.  ...As the comment above says, let's get a [mcve] so we can see what you've tried so far, and what's not working about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, you can [delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) methods.
This is similar to making the method private.
However, it expresses the programmer's intent and results in more descriptive compiler errors.

```
class classA{
   operator classB();
   operator classC();

   //Remove this comparison possibility:
   classC operator ==(classC secondObject) = delete;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the operator and make it `private`. Then, nobody else will be able to call it.