# Referencing and dereferencing in the same instruction

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Wondering through the LLVM source code i stumbled upon this line of code

```
MachineInstr *MI = &*I;
```

I am kinda newb in c++ and the difference between references and pointers is quite obscure to me, and I think that it has something to do about this difference, but this operation makes no sense to me. Does anybody have an explanation for doing that?

Comment: Is it the `&*` you're wondering about?

Comment: @jalf: Concerning the title "Referencing and dereferencing in the same instruction", I believe everything points to yes ;)

Comment: @jalf: Exactly :) I don't see any reason to do that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `I` is probably some sort of iterator or smart pointer which has the unary `operator*()` overloaded to yield a `MachineInstr&`. If you want to get a built-in pointer to the object referenced by `I` you get a reference to the object using `*I` and then you take the address of this reference, using `&*I`.

Comment: `I` is actually an iterator. This makes totally sense :)

Comment: If `I` is *just* a pointer, this doesn't make sense. Most likely it is a smart pointer (a class which "behaves" like a pointer). For a raw pointer, the `*` and `&` effectively cancel each others out. But for smart pointers, this is a way to get a *raw* pointer to the pointed-to object

Answer (score 2):

C++ allows overloading of the dereference operator, so it is using the overloaded method on the object, and then it is taking the address of the result and putting it into the pointer.

Comment: Note that the address-of operator (prefix `&`) can also be redefined, but sane code doesn't do that, so one can usually ignore it.

Comment: @delnan: incidentally, even in that case you can still get the address with [strange tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6494591/214671).

Comment: @delnan that would be so much fun :P

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
MachineInstr *MI = &*I;
```

Dereferences `I` with `*`, and gets the address of its result with `&` then assigns it to `MI` which is a pointer to `MachineInstr`. It looks like `I` is an iterator, so `*I` is the value stored in a container since iterators define the `*` operator to return the item at iteration point. The container (e.g. a list) must be containing a `MachineInstr`. This might be a `std::list<MachineInstr>`.