# std::addressof - strange implementation

Tags: c++, std

So a few days ago i learned about std::addressof. At http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof a possible implementation is given:

```
template< class T >
T* addressof(T& arg) 
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
               &const_cast<char&>(
                  reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(arg)));
}
```

As far i see this can simply be implemented like:

```
template<typename T>
T* addressof( T& var )
{
    return &var;
}
```

Why the guys at cppreference chose to implement it with 3 casts? Is there any detail I am missing that is making their implementation better. What is the point in using volatile when all you do is cast?

Comment: Overloading the address of operator breaks the second implementation.

Comment: have a look at this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494591/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-address-of-an-object/6495205#6495205

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it could be implemented like in your example, there would be no need for it. The point is that it gives you the address of an object, even if the address-of `operator&` for that type has been overloaded.

Comment: Aha I see. And what is the point of casting to const volatile&, instead of just char&?

Comment: @GeneralFailure That is so that you can pass `const` or `volatile` qualified lvalues. You can try removing that to see.