# Possible implementation of std::addressof

Tags: c++, c++11, const-cast, addressof

This could be a duplicate[[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682995/stdaddressof-strange-implementation) but, the answer is rather short and not very clear. In a possible implementation like this:

```
template <class T>
T * addressof(T & v)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<T *>(& const_cast<char&>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(v)));
}
```

why is the `const_cast` needed?

Comment: i posted it already...

Comment: don't create another question, just ask in comment.

Comment: okay, sure, but only this time.:)

Comment: btw... a flag as "Possible duplicate" isnt the end of the world. It just means that imho your question does not add enough to the linked question and that imho you could improve your question by making more clear what you thing is missing on that answer

Comment: @user2338150 The reason `const_cast` is required is because compiler won't allow you to implicitely cast away `const/volatile` qualifiers when doing `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think that the answer to the other question simply does not fully answer the question. It should not be accepted and OP should ask more questions in comments.

Comment: @StoryTeller I found a dupe that answers how the whole thing works.  That should satisfy the OP

Comment: @freakish - The dup Nathan linked is an exact one. It answer this question fully (The const cast is needed because of the reinterpret cast, because that is needed, due to). The link in the post, and the one tobi voted as a dup, is not one however.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Yes, I was just agreeing with you :)

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I've been looking for, possibly more.:) I'll read it fully first. Thank you for pointing me to the answer.

Comment: I did vote for reopen, because first it seemed like a "possible dupe" but turened out not to be a duplicate. Imho everything went well here and SO mechanics proved once again to work ok. However, what I dont like is the attidute of getting offended on the smallest critisism and imho OP should remove the "dismissive" from the question because it isnt appropriate to someone who took the time to write an answer (no matter how short it is)

Comment: @tobi303: I'll take that as constructive criticism, but obviously I had reason to get 'offended'. It occurred to me that you did not even read the question completely, as the link you posted was the same one mentioned in the question. Besides, the answer mentioned in the post was plainly '...'(fill in a more appropriate word if you must). Anyways, the point of asking and answering is for the benefit of more than both the parties. So, I'm removing the comment posted earlier, and I express my apologies if you found something rude.