# Conversion from std::vector<T>::iterator to void *

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I am trying to convert `std::vector<T>::iterator` to `void *`, but getting compiler error as wrong conversion. is there any way?

Comment: Can you show the code and the applicable error?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that. If you describe the problem you're trying to solve by doing this, you might get a working solution to the actual problem. (This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If the compiler is complaining then you are probably doing something very bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the pointer to the vector element with dereference:

```
vector<Type>::iterator i = ...;
void* data = &*i;
```

Or to vector data:

```
void* data = vec.data();
```

Comment: Or just `void *data = static_cast<void *>(vec.data());`

Comment: @ForceBru or even drop the cast : every pointer is implicitly convertible to (but not from) `void*`.

Comment: `struct evil { char* operator&() const { return nullptr; } }; std::vector<evil>`: `&` is unreliable in generic code.

Comment: Yakk, see this question for discussion on generic addressof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494591/how-can-i-reliably-get-an-objects-address-when-operator-is-overloaded