# confused about implemention of offsetof in msvc?

Tags: c++

in MSVC, `offsetof` implemented as:

```
#define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
```

My question is:

- why `reinterpret_cast`?
- why `volatile`?
- why `size_t`, not `ptrdiff_t`?

Comment: `size_t` because the standard says so. Don't you worry about the rest, let STL worry about that.

Comment: One reason that `offsetof` is in the standard C library is that it can't be implemented portably. So the answer to "why is it written that way" is simply "because it works".

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494591/how-can-i-reliably-get-an-objects-address-when-operator-is-overloaded/6495205#6495205

Answer (score -2):

`&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>(expr)` is also the code used to implement `std::addressof`. `std::addressof` is necessary because C++ allows overloading the unary-`&` operator, but the actual library function can't be used here prior to C++17, when it is marked `constexpr`.

`size_t` rather than `ptrdiff_t` because that's what the standard says it has to return.

Edit: while *technically* the standard doesn't directly specify this case, in practice compilers are forced to cover it due to other logic and historical practice.

Answer (score -3):

> ```
> why reinterpret_cast?
> ```

reinterpret_cast<>() is the only way to convert a pointer to a size_t

> ```
> why volatile?
> ```

volatile prevents the optimizer to optimize away the expression `(((s*)0)->m))`.

> ```
> why size_t, not ptrdiff_t?
> ```

`offsetof()`  returns an offset, not the number of elements between two pointers.

Comment: That's not what `volatile` is doing at all, here.