# c++ get address of variable without operator&

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, addressof

I have got a class that has overloaded unary `operator&`. The objects of that type were created using `new`, so address of variable was accessible but now I need to use static object. Is it possible to get its address?

Comment: Is the *unary* `operator&` in fact overloaded?

Comment: @FredLarson I was surprised too look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators

Comment: @KugBuBu: Yes, I saw that it can be overloaded. But the question is not explicit on which actually is overloaded in this case. I've seen classes overload binary `operator&` (say, for string concatenation). It's unusual to overload the unary operator.

Comment: @FredLarson: The question would be rather trivial if it weren't about the unary operator.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Exactly why it's important information.

Comment: Essentially the same question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1142607/57428

Comment: @MikeSeymour Nvm, I was being silly. This is why staying up for more than 20 hours is never a good idea.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since C++11, you may use the function [std::addressof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/addressof/)

Answer (score 36):

In C++11 or later, `std::addressof(object)`, declared by the `<memory>` header.

Historically, it was more grotesque, especially if you wanted to deal with `const` and `volatile` qualifiers correctly. One possibility used by Boost's implementation of `addressof` is

```
reinterpret_cast<T*>(
    &const_cast<char&>(
        reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(object)))
```

first adding qualifers while converting to `char&` so that `reinterpret_cast` would work however `object` were qualified; then removing them so that the final conversion would work; then finally taking the address and converting that to the correct type. As long as `T` has the same qualifiers as `object` (which it will as a template parameter deduced from `object`), the resulting pointer will be correctly qualified.

Comment: This is also how `std::addressof` is implemented by GCC

Comment: And pretty much the same implementation for VC++.